# Javascript .onclick function to redirect to other page

Tags: javascript

Hi i'm trying to validate user typing some data and then redirect the user to other web page, the alerts works nice but the location.href is doing nothing, please help.

```
window.onload = function(){
    var send = document.getElementById('send');
    var email = document.getElementById('email');       
    var pass = document.getElementById('pass');

    send.onclick = function(){     
        var data1 = email.value;
        var data2 = pass.value;

        if(data1==''){
            alert('Please enter an email address');
        }
        else if(data2==''){
            alert('Please enter your password');
        }
        else{
            window.location.href = 'myotherpage.html';
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Solution:

All I needed was to add a `return false;` after the location to stop the script and continue to the redirection instruction, thanks all for the replies.

Comment: Try ```location.href = xxx ```

Comment: Use window.location.replace('http://example.com/');

Comment: @AyrtonDumas - that's the same thing...

Comment: what is envia? A submit button?

Comment: Try `window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com")`;

Comment: Have you checked whether the execution reaches this line of code?

Comment: @JonathanNewton Actually, setting href works just fine.

Comment: `window.location.href = '/myotherpage.html';`

Comment: envia was a mistake now i fixed to 'send'

Comment: If send is a button/link, it will redirect the page. You would need to cancel the default action with either `return false;` or `event.preventDefaut();`

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function(){
var send = document.getElementById('send');
var email = document.getElementById('email');       
var pass = document.getElementById('pass');

send.onclick = function(){     
    var data1 = email.value;
    var data2 = pass.value;

    if(data1==''){
        alert('Please enter an email address');
    }
    else if(data2==''){
        alert('Please enter your password');
    }
    else{
        window.location.href = '/myotherpage.html';
    }
}
```

}

changed some variables and added a "/" to  window.location.href

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code to this and got it working just fine:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var send = document.getElementById('send');
    var email = document.getElementById('email');       
    var pass = document.getElementById('pass');

    send.onclick = function(){     
        var data1 = email.value;
        var data2 = pass.value;

        if(data1==''){
            alert('Please enter an email address');
        }
        else if(data2==''){
            alert('Please enter your password');
        }
        else{
            window.location = 'myotherpage.html';
        }
    }
}
```

I changed your `valor` variables to `data`, `envia` to `send`, and `window.location.href` to `window.location`.

Comment: thanks, i didn't notice that when i put the code here, i changed some names so everyone can understand, but it still don't work.

Comment: @AlvaroBascunan I think you have something else going on with your page then. This code works just fine as you can see with this codepen: http://codepen.io/kodie/pen/VKGgpN